# Varargs of type Class in Java

Tags: java, generics, superclass, variadic-functions

If I, for example, have a method that uses varargs for Class types that extends a super class like 
this:

```
public static <E extends Example> void test(Class<E>... es){}
```

Then I try to call that method with two different subclasses of Example, I can only do so if I make an array with the two classes in it.

```
//this does not work
test(E1.class,E2.class);
//this does work
test(new Class[]{E1.class,E2.class});
public class E1 extends Example {}
public class E2 extends Example {}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line doesn't compile:

```
test(E1.class,E2.class);
```

There is only one type parameter `E`, and Java must match the inferred types of the arguments exactly.  It cannot infer `Example`, because the objects are `Class<E1>` and `Class<E2>`, not `Class<Example>`.  The invariance of Java generics prevents this from happening.

You can work around this by introducing an upper bound wildcard on `test`'s generic type parameter:

```
public static <E extends Example> void test(Class<? extends E>... es)
```

This allows Java to infer `Example` for `E`, by satisfying the upper bound wildcard with `E1` and `E2`.

The second line creates a raw array of `Class`es, bypassing generics and generating an "unchecked call" warning.

```
new Class[]{E1.class,E2.class}
```

If you were to attempt to provide a type argument to `Class` here, you would get a compiler error with any half-way reasonable type parameter:

```
// Needs Class<Example> but found Class<E1> and Class<E2>
test(new Class<Example>[]{E1.class,E2.class});

// Needs Class<E1> but found Class<E2>
test(new Class<E1>[]{E1.class,E2.class}); 

// Needs Class<E2> but found Class<E1>
test(new Class<E2>[]{E1.class,E2.class});
```

Satisfying the inference by using a wildcard here just uncovers the real problem here -- generic array creation.

```
// Generic array creation
test(new Class<? extends Example>[]{E1.class,E2.class});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It was never detrimental to my program, but I've definitely been scratching my head at it for a while. I really appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You define the generic E of a single class that extends Example.  You can't reference two different classes in your call because it won't know what type E is.  It expects only one type.

Although this does not work:

```
test(E1.class, E2.class);
```

This does:

```
test(E1.class, E1.class);
```

The reason you can do it with an array is because of type erasure.  The compiler doesn't see that the classes within the array are different.

If you change your method to accept any class that extends `Example` it will work.

```
public static void test(Class<? extends Example>...classes)
```

Comment: I think you've explained it pretty well.  But to be equal to the OP's example, your signature should be `public static <E extends Example> void test(Class<? extends E>... classes)`.  It will (in any case) give an `-Xlint:unchecked` warning, though.

Comment: @5gon12eder: The signature you gave and the one in this answer are exactly equivalent, i.e. they accept the exact same class of arguments. The simpler one (the one given in this answer) should always be preferred because the type parameter is unnecessary.

Comment: @newacct They accept the same class of arguments but if you want to refer to the generic type, you'll need the more verbose syntax.  Since in the OP, `test` returns `void` and has an empty body, you could argue that we don't want to refer to the type anyway, but speaking generally, the verbose syntax is also more powerful.

Comment: @5gon12eder: It is not any "more powerful" from an outside code point of view. Even in the extremely unlikely case the code needs to refer to `E`, your method can simply pass the argument onto a private method that is generic.

Comment: @5gon12eder since the method was void, their was no explicit need to declare E.